# Duplicate values of every data row

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

There are 2 rows in my table and I'm receiving values within my site as follows:

[image: table data]

I should only be receiving 2 rows so I'm not sure what I've done wrong with my code?

```
if (binForm.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    int rowCounter = binForm.Rows.Count;
    int increment = 0;
    while (rowCounter > 0)
    {
        tableData.Append("<tr><td>" + binForm.Rows[increment]["binType"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + binForm.Rows[increment]["binColour"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + binForm.Rows[increment]["date"].ToString() + "</td><tr>");
        increment++;
        rowCounter--;

    }

  }
```

This is how the form is generated:

```
DataTable binForm = new DataTable();

MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT bin.binType, bin.binColour, missedbin.date FROM bin INNER JOIN missedbin ON missedbin.address_addressID=bin.address_addressID WHERE '" + sessionVarAddress.ToString() + "' = bin.address_addressID ", connect);
dataAdapter.Fill(binForm);
```

here is the actual data in the bin table.

[image: tabledata]

and missedbin table.

[image: table2data]

EDIT: It seems as though as suggested my sql query is incorrect as it is returning 4 rows.

Comment: So show us what is in `binForm` or how you generate `binForm`

Comment: Your query is probably wrong. I see the dates are different, so there are not really duplicates. Check what is in `binForm`. EDIT: Show us what is in missedbin table.

Comment: Made requested edit.

Comment: @Richard1996 You join using address_addressID - thats why you have two dates for each record.Because there are two records with addressID = 3.

Comment: Ah okay I see thanks, is there any other column i can use that would allow me to have the correct rows?

Comment: @Richard1996 I don't know this is your program. Please rethink what outcome you want. If the data in db is ok, you must group your join to for example return only rows with the latest date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be the join, not this snip-it of code.

if you join on a field with 2 entries the same, it will double up as per this example. please go back and check your query.

Comment: Ah I see so would it be better to use 2 select statements instead?

Comment: we would need to see  an example of the data to best determine the correct course of action

Comment: can you please provide an example of the data to better explain

Comment: if you look at the address_addressID you have 2 rows with the same id,

so what you are getting is each row matching to each other, and duplicating the data. you should be storing a primary key in one of the tables in order to match back on a one to one basis's

Comment: ah i see so for instance use bin id as a FK in missedbin?

Comment: yep you've got it.